# Default integer length in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am reading some script which is written in Perl and I don't understand it. I have never used Perl before. I've read someting about scalars and that confuses me. For an example look at this code:

```
my $sim_packets = 5;
my $sim_length = $payload_length * 2 * $sim_packets;
push @data, (1...$sim_length * 10);
my $data_32bit = 0;
```

if I use after this:

```
$data_32bit = shift @data;
```

What is length of `$data_32bit` in bits?

I ask this because I have another array in this code: `@payload`, and this line confuses me:

```
push @payload, ($data_32bit >> 24) & 0xff, 
               ($data_32bit >> 16) & 0xff, 
               ($data_32bit >> 8)  & 0xff, 
               ($data_32bit)       & 0xff;
```

`$data_32bit` is 32 bit long?

Comment: Code shown, `$payload_length` is undef, so `$data_32bit == 0`

Comment: What is `$payload_length` set to? `shift` is a function that operates on arrays, not the mathematical function. See [`perldoc -f shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html)

Answer (score 3):

Oh boy,

```
 push @payload, ($data_32bit >> 24) & 0xff, ($data_32bit >> 16) & 0xff, ($data_32bit >> 8) & 0xff, ($data_32bit) & 0xff;
```

Somebody apparently needs to

```
perldoc -f pack
perldoc -f unpack
```

Regarding your question, `$data_32bit` is not 32bit long, just becasue the term `32bit` appears in its name. If you need to know how exactly it is represented, you should go for `Data::Dumper`.

Perl stores integers in the mantissa of a native floating point number, so it really depends on the machine architecture. With IEEE, it should be something like 53 bits.

Answer (score 2):

> If I understand correctly third line of this code created array: 1..50?

It added to an array rather than creating one.

The scalars added consist of numbers starting with 1 and going up to and including `$payload_length * 2 * $sim_packets * 10`, which is `$payload_length * 100`.

`$payload_length` is unlikely to be 1/2, so I suspect the number of scalars added is more than the 50 you mentioned.

---

> What is length of $data_32bit in bits?

What does that even mean?

The size of the scalar of 24 *bytes* on one of my system.

```
$ perl -MDevel::Size=total_size -E'$i=123; say total_size $i'
24
```

The amount of bits required to store the value:

```
ceil(log($payload_length * 100) / log(2))
```

In this case, the author appears to be indicating the value will/should fit in 32 bits. That will be the case unless `$payload_length` exceeds some number larger than 40,000,000.

---

> and this line confuses me:

It adds four values to the array. The four values correspond to the bytes of `$data_32bit` when stored as a unsigned two's complement number with the most significant byte first.